# Laravel 5 - How to Query if DB Value is Array

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

In database, I have "categories" and "products" table. In "products" table, there is a category_ids column which is an array, because the product has more than one categories.

What I want is to query the product that has category_ids of 1. I am trying to do like this, it is works, but I want a simpler way how to do.

```
$catId = 1; //category ID
$allProducts = Product::all(); // get all products
foreach ($allProducts as $product) { //loop all the products
  if(in_array($catId, $product->category_ids)) { // check if category ID is in array of its product categories
    $products[] = Product::find($product->id);
  }
}
```

As you can see above,I must loop through all the products to check if category ID is exist in product categories array.

Is there a better way so it is not checking all the products?

Answer (score 0):

All code is OK except one line .

```
$catId = 1; //category ID
$allProducts = Product::all(); // get all products
foreach ($allProducts as $product) { //loop all the products
    $cats = explode(',',$product->category_ids);  
    if(in_array($catId, $cats)) { // check if category ID is in array of its product categories
        $products[] = Product::find($product->id);
    }
}
```

I added this line. I assume that multiple categories of a product will be stored in a single field with comma separated (Although its not the correct way, you need to create a M2M table)

```
$cats = explode(',',$product->category_ids);
```

So In in_array function, 2nd element should be an array. and Because of output of explode, $cats is an array.

```
 in_array($catId, $cats)
```

Comment: Hi Naveed, thanks for answering. But I think you missunderstood here:), sorry. The value in db is array, I already added the attribute casting array for  category_ids column, so there is no need to use explode. The thing is my code above is works, But I want to know if there is a better way without looping all the products. Something like whereIn, but it is the reverse function of whereIn. whereIn is checking the db value if it is in array. I want a reverse function of that, i am glad if that exist.

Comment: AH ok, then my answer will be NO. because in_array save developers time so its good to use that :)